# Centos 7 - High Load, low CPU, low IO wait, no processed maked as D

Tags: centos, top, load-average

I've got a CentOS 7 VM which seems to be stuck with quite high load (8-10). CPU usage is around 25%, there is no IO wait and there are no processes marked as D in top. I've been looking around as much as I can but these seem to be the only three causes of high load that I can find. Does anybody else know what else could be causing high load? I'm stumped!

[top output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk6a0.png)

[Webmin dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is3sM.png)

Comment: Why do you believe that the load is high?

Comment: I ran pretty much the same set up on a CentOS 6 OpenVZ container and the load was around 2.5. I was surprised to see it jump to 8 on a Hetzner Cloud VM running CentOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

I think those numbers are quite normal. Your CPU usage is 50%, and not 25% (don't forget the sys load - userprocesses waiting for the kernel to compute something also count as running!) ... Let's take a look at the definition of system load: [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/194642/understanding-the-load-average-on-linux-and-other-unix-like-systems/)

A rough summary would be "the average number of running processes (non-idle) over time". From your top statistik, I see quite a lot of processes having a cpu load over 1%, so it is quite normal, that your system load is high.

Take note that the load numbers are not really comparable between two systems: it depends on the sampling frequency etc... So if you recently moved to a different cloud, it is totally normal that those numbers differ!

[here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.7/admin-guide/cpu-load.html) is quite a good explanation why these numbers aren't really comparable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. If it looks okay I'll stop worrying! It does seems to be responsive enough.

Comment: Absolutely okay! The responsiveness is more important than the system load...